# spark dataframes : reading json having duplicate column names but different datatypes

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, jackson, jsonschema

I have json data like below where version field is the differentiator -

`file_1  = {"version": 1, "stats": {"hits":20}}`

`file_2  = {"version": 2, "stats": [{"hour":1,"hits":10},{"hour":2,"hits":12}]}`

In the new format, stats column is now `Arraytype(StructType)`.

Earlier only file_1 was needed so I was using

```
spark.read.schema(schema_def_v1).json(path)
```

Now I need to read both these type of multiple json files which come together. I cannot define stats as string in schema_def as that would affect the `corruptrecord` feature(for stats column) which checks malformed json and schema compliance of all the fields.

**Example df output required in 1 read only -**

```
version | hour | hits
1       | null | 20
2       | 1    | 10
2       | 2    | 12
```

I have tried to read with `mergeSchema` option but that makes stats field String type.

Also, I have tried making two dataframes   by filtering on the version field, and applying `spark.read.schema(schema_def_v1).json(df_v1.toJSON)`. Here also stats column becomes `String` type.

I was thinking if while reading, I could parse the df column headers as `stats_v1` and `stats_v2` on basis of data-types can solve the problem. Please help with any possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

`UDF` to check string or array, if it is string it will convert string to an array.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, JObject}
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.write
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

object Parse {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    def toArray(data:String) = {
      val json_data = (parse(data))
      if(json_data.isInstanceOf[JObject]) write(List(json_data)) else data
    }
}

val toJsonArray = udf(Parse.toArray _)
```

```
scala> "ls -ltr /tmp/data".!
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 srinivas  root  37 Jun 26 17:49 file_1.json
-rw-r--r--  1 srinivas  root  69 Jun 26 17:49 file_2.json
res4: Int = 0

scala> val df = spark.read.json("/tmp/data").select("stats","version")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [stats: string, version: bigint]

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- stats: string (nullable = true)
 |-- version: long (nullable = true)
```

```
scala> df.show(false)
+-------+-------------------------------------------+
|version|stats                                      |
+-------+-------------------------------------------+
|1      |{"hits":20}                                |
|2      |[{"hour":1,"hits":10},{"hour":2,"hits":12}]|
+-------+-------------------------------------------+
```

**Output**

```
scala> 

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = ArrayType(MapType(StringType,IntegerType))

df
.withColumn("json_stats",explode(from_json(toJsonArray($"stats"),schema)))
.select(
    $"version",
    $"stats",
    $"json_stats".getItem("hour").as("hour"),
    $"json_stats".getItem("hits").as("hits")
).show(false)

+-------+-------------------------------------------+----+----+
|version|stats                                      |hour|hits|
+-------+-------------------------------------------+----+----+
|1      |{"hits":20}                                |null|20  |
|2      |[{"hour":1,"hits":10},{"hour":2,"hits":12}]|1   |10  |
|2      |[{"hour":1,"hits":10},{"hour":2,"hits":12}]|2   |12  |
+-------+-------------------------------------------+----+----+
```

**Without UDF**

```
scala> val schema = ArrayType(MapType(StringType,IntegerType))

scala> val expr = when(!$"stats".contains("[{"),concat(lit("["),$"stats",lit("]"))).otherwise($"stats")

df
.withColumn("stats",expr)
.withColumn("stats",explode(from_json($"stats",schema)))
.select(
    $"version",
    $"stats",
    $"stats".getItem("hour").as("hour"),
    $"stats".getItem("hits").as("hits")
)
.show(false)

+-------+-----------------------+----+----+
|version|stats                  |hour|hits|
+-------+-----------------------+----+----+
|1      |[hits -> 20]           |null|20  |
|2      |[hour -> 1, hits -> 10]|1   |10  |
|2      |[hour -> 2, hits -> 12]|2   |12  |
+-------+-----------------------+----+----+
```

Comment: val schema_def = StructType.fromDDL(version int, stats *struct<hits:int,hour int> 
 OR array<struct<hits:int,hour int>> OR string*,  _corrupt_record String). I want to read with schema definition like this and collect corrupt_record column for malformed json and schema mismatches. Reading stats as String doesn't help.

Comment: can you explain why reading string will not help ? & above example I am reading as string & then parsing into array.

Comment: file_1  = {"version": 1, "stats": {"hits":"abcd"}} .Considering this type of bad json data in hits field, I have the functionality of capturing corrupt_record in my current solution, which I believe is not going to work with String type in this new problem of mixed datatypes.Your solution works but I do not want to lose this added feature. You may refer section (A) here https://blog.knoldus.com/apache-spark-handle-corrupt-bad-records/

Comment: don't apply schema while loading.. just load all files spark will figure it out schema. once loaded you transform required columns. in this case stats is having different data types so spark will add super type i.e. string.

Comment: if you apply schema while loading it will throwing corrupt_record as records will not matching with your schema.

Comment: That is exactly what is happening.So I am trying to read as string then make two dataframes by filtering on version and then calling the read function again to capture corrupt_record w.r.t schema_type_1 -- spark.read.schema(schema_def_v1).json(df_v1.toJSON) . But as you mentioned the field is the super type string, I would like to make it to structType or array<StructType> after filtering and before passing to read function. Any suggestions?

Comment: why are you doing such complex you can follow above solution it will work. .. super type is string once you convert to json again its two data types.. that is one file has ```object``` & other file has ```array of object``` to fix this , i am converting ```object``` data to ```array of object```.

Comment: If you are using python, try converting ```"stats": {"hits":"abcd"}``` object to ```"stats": [{"hits":"abcd"}]``` and then use ```from_json``` with schema & explode result.

Comment: I have huge data and capturing corrupt_record is critical. Looking for a efficient way to do so.

Comment: are you using python ??, if yes, write udf to convert string to array of string. then apply schema it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Read the second file first, explode `stats`, use schema to read first file.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import  explode

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

file_1 = {"version": 1, "stats": {"hits": 20}}

file_2 = {"version": 2, "stats": [{"hour": 1, "hits": 10}, {"hour": 2, "hits": 12}]}

df1 = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([file_2])).withColumn('stats', explode('stats'))
schema = df1.schema

spark.read.schema(schema).json(sc.parallelize([file_1])).printSchema()

output >> root
 |-- stats: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- hits: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- hour: long (nullable = true)
 |-- version: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i dont have any identification among many such files. They're all mixed

Comment: Also I think if you show() the df in your code, the stats part of file_2 would display as null due to schema being used not having the ArrayType

Comment: my bad, I will change that

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can read the JSON files using [spark.read.text](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.text) and then parse the `value` with [json_tuple](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.json_tuple), [from_json](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json). notice for `stats` field we use `coalesce` to parse fields based on two or more schema. (add `wholetext=True` as an argument of spark.read.text if each file contains a single JSON document cross multiple lines)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import json_tuple, coalesce, from_json, array

df = spark.read.text("/path/to/all/jsons/")

schema_1 = "array<struct<hour:int,hits:int>>"
schema_2 = "struct<hour:int,hits:int>"

df.select(json_tuple('value', 'version', 'stats').alias('version', 'stats')) \
    .withColumn('status', coalesce(from_json('stats', schema_1), array(from_json('stats', schema_2)))) \
    .selectExpr('version', 'inline_outer(status)') \
    .show()
+-------+----+----+
|version|hour|hits|
+-------+----+----+
|      2|   1|  10|
|      2|   2|  12|
|      1|null|  20|
+-------+----+----+
```

Comment: I'm using scala and I just found that we can parse the mixed types  stats column without coalesce and just using the ArrayType schema_def in the from_json function

Comment: One important need was to capture bad datatype records in stats column, but I read that from_json function with third parameter - options Map<key,value> does not support PERMISSIVE mode or columnNameOfCorruptRecord until spark 3.0

Comment: yes, you can use `array<map<string,string>>` in from_json function, that will do it. But you do read files using spark.read.text and then parse this field? @Abhishek

Comment: wait, I think that will still miss `map<string,string>`, similar to array of structs. so why just do it using coalesce instead of relying on other options.

Comment: I did spark.read.json. It gave me stats as StringType and I applied schema_1 in from_json to parse both the types in stats field at once